# Is there a scientific survey on the number of Cryptocurrency fails / scams?

Tags: blockchain

Is there a **scientific** survey/ publication/ paper about how many of the 1597 cryptocurrencies/ blockchains listed by coinmarketcap.com or similar, might be scam, have failed or are not even developed?

I wonder how many of those hundreds of blockchains around might be *serious* projects.

Blog entries or estimations might also be useful to me, but I would like reliable information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bitcoin.com](https://news.bitcoin.com/46-last-years-icos-failed-already/)

> Having completed an extensive study into last year’s crowdsales, news.Bitcoin.com can report that 46% of them are effectively dead already – despite raising over $104 million.

[Satis Group's Cryptocurrency Research](https://medium.com/satis-group/ico-quality-development-trading-e4fef28df04f)

> On the basis of the above classification, we found that approximately 81% of ICO’s were Scams, ~6% Failed, ~5% had Gone Dead, and ~8% went on to trade on a exchange.

Lastly, Bitcoin.com also mentions that in an MIT-authored research paper, [Initial Coin Offerings and the Value of Crypto Tokens](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3137213), it was ["found [that] only between 5% to 25% of ICOs are frauds."](https://news.bitcoin.com/80-of-icos-are-scams-only-8-reach-an-exchange/) However, I couldn't find evidence of this claim in the paper mentioned.

Comment: Thank you, that are many sources, which I can totally use!